# Access VBA Copy images is only copying first image

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2013 and have a query "qryMatchingStyle" and field "FilePath" that contain a list of files paths to copy images from.  I then have a table, "tmpDestFolders" and field "FlatFile" to copy the images to.  I call the below Function that is in a Module to copy the images - however, it only ever copies the first image even though they are more - why is this?  Is my loop incorrect or do I need to put this in a Class Module?

```
Public Function CopyStyle()

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strEmail As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FromPath As String
Dim fso As Object

Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FromPath = DLookup("FilePath", "qryMatchingStyle")
ToPath = DLookup("FlatFile", "tmpDestFolders")

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

strSQL = "[qryMatchingStyle]"  'source of recordset
rst.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

If Not rst.EOF Then
  Do While Not rst.EOF
  'copy file code here

  Call fso.CopyFile(FromPath, ToPath)

  rst.MoveNext
  Loop
End If

Set rst = Nothing

'Update flag to say style was copied
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE qryMatchingStyle INNER JOIN tblLocalStyleCol ON qryMatchingStyle.Style = tblLocalStyleCol.Style SET tblLocalStyleCol.[Style Copied] = True", -1

'MsgBox "All matching style images copied"       

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `FromPath` and `ToPath` are assigned once; they are not fecteched from the Recordset. Try this:

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
   FromPath = rst.Fields("FilePath").Value
   ToPath = rst.Fields("FlatFile").Value
   Call fso.CopyFile(FromPath, ToPath)
   rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

p.s. there is  no need for the `If Not rst.EOF` statement that envelops this loop, nor for the first assignments of `FromPath` and `ToPath`. These can be removed form your code.

Comment: @Micahel glad to know it helped.